# AG Grid Community v22.1.1 missing aria properties

Tags: ag-grid-react

I'm using AG Grid community@22.1.1 with ag-grid-react@22.1.1.

In the rendered DOM I see all the accessible elements has role="presentation", and unselectable="on" which makes the keyboard navigation and screen reader features fail, so need help to make it accessible with proper aria attributes which I see working in this demo URL (https://www.ag-grid.com/example/?theme=ag-theme-material).

Also wanted to know if the accessibility support wasn't added in the older releases in my case its ag-grid-react@22.1.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7145.png)

I tried adding these configs, but no luck

```
ensureDomOrder={true}
suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}
suppressRowVirtualisation={true}
```